# WP_Query that filters based on custom relationship field

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field

I have two custom post types: work and clients. On the work posts I set up a custom relationship field (client_name) where you can select one of the client posts.

On the work post I now want to check how many other work posts there are with the same client and get some other data from those posts. Here's the code I have so far:

```
<?php
  $client = get_field('client_name');
  $work_args  = array(
    'post_type' => 'work',
    'meta_key' => 'client_name',
    'meta_value' => $client
  );
  $work_query = new WP_Query($work_args);
  if ($work_query->have_posts()):
  while ($work_query->have_posts()): $work_query->the_post();
?>
        /* Do something here */
<?php
  endwhile; endif;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```

To be clear: the problem is not in the /* Do something here */ part, it's in the meta_value. I can't figure out what to put there so I can see if it matches the current client.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Hi! So your call to `get_field` without a post ID will return the value for the current post: is that what you want? Is there a current post? (i.e. are you in a loop?) If `$client` has a valid value, this should work. Have you checked the value of `$work_args` ?

Comment: Thanks @MacPrawn - Yes, I want the value for the current post. This code is placed inside a loop. When I check the value of `$work_args` it says it's an array. That's actually the same for `$clients`: it's an array. So I also tried stuff like `'meta_value' => $client->ID` of `'meta_value' => $client[0]` but to no avail.

Comment: I see: so the problem likely is with your $client variable. You say it's an array, but what does it contain? Try `print_r($client);` to view the array's content. The `get_field` function's return value will change based on the field's type.

Comment: `print_r($client);` outputs `Array ( [0] => 68 )`, but I'm not sure where that leaves me, to be honest.

Comment: BTW, 68 is the correct ID of the post I'm trying to 'filter' for

Comment: Great - so `'meta_value' => $client[0]` then really should work. Do you get an error message at all, on screen or in your logs? Or does it just not find any records? Also, your field is called "client_name", but you query it with an ID - is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

well, I guess the problem is I'm trying to compare an array with a value. I made a workaround that gets me to where I need to go:

```
<?php
  $client = get_field('client_name');
  $work_args  = array(
    'post_type' => 'work'
  );
  $work_query = new WP_Query($work_args);
  if ($work_query->have_posts()):
  while ($work_query->have_posts()): $work_query->the_post();
?>
        $client2 = get_field('client_name');
    if ($client[0] == $client2[0] ){
         /*do something here*/
    }
<?php
  endwhile; endif;
  wp_reset_query();
?>
```